# Isolating run sequence definition seems inconsistent

Tags: unicode

I've been reading [Unicode Standard Annex #9](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/), which describes the Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm, and I've hit a snag in [section BD13](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#BD13), the definition of an *isolating run sequence*.

> An isolating run sequence is a maximal sequence of level runs such that for all level runs except the last one in the sequence, **the last character of the run is an isolate initiator whose matching PDI is the first character of the next level run in the sequence**.

How can this be the case? [Section BD9](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#BD9), which defines the *matching PDI* of an isolate initiator, says that

> an isolate initiator and its matching PDI are always assigned the same explicit embedding level

and [section BD7](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#BD7) defines a level run as

> a maximal substring of characters that have the same embedding level

This would seem to indicate that an isolate initiator and its matching PDI cannot belong to consecutive level runs. Either they should belong to the same level run, or there should be at least one level run between them.

What's the resolution of this apparent inconsistency? Is there a distinction between an "explicit embedding level" and an "embedding level"? Is one of the quotes I'm relying on non-normative and not completely accurate? Are isolating run sequences just always one level run long?

In case the wording changes, this question is based on [revision 33](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/tr9-33.html), the current revision of the annex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing up this question, I figured out the examples under section BD13 and how they resolve the issue. An isolating run sequence is **not contiguous**. Its elements are not required to be consecutive level runs; indeed, they must be separated by level runs belonging to other isolating run sequences. This should be made more explicit.